# How to create an icon with overlapping images in android?

Tags: android

In the android app that I am building, I want to create a launcher icon for an album activity. The album activity will be nothing but a grid view displaying all the images.

Now, the launcher icon that I want to build shall show a couple of images partially overlapping one another.

Are there any libraries or standard android views that can help me do this?

Below is how I want the launcher icon to look:

[image]

Comment: `the launcher icon that I want to build` The laucher icon (properly said) is a **static** thing. Or do you mean the ActionBar/ToolBar icon?

Comment: I agree with @DerGolem, Launcher icon are generated static so there no required for any libraries or view.

Comment: @DerGolem: It will be a static thing, a part of a layout activity

Comment: So, what's the question about? Open Gimp (or whatever), prepare the icon by overlaying 2 images, resize it and put in its various density folders and you're done.

Comment: Ok, it seems I missed a couple of details! The content and the number of items per album is dynamic. It will vary from user to user. A user can create as many albums and put as many images that he wants in an album. Now once an album has been crated and its pictures have been selected, the launcher icon should reflect the 3 with latest time stamps.

Comment: As I said, you **can't change** the launcher icon (which is the app icon). You only create it once and for all.

Comment: @DerGolem: The "launcher icon" that I am talking about is not the app's launcher icon. This will be a view embedded in one of the activities in the app. This view's "on click" event will open the album activity. From a utility perspective, it will be very much similar to a normal "button". Please see the image at "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tmV2pe9vyyE/Ua2pDOGvcvI/AAAAAAAADMM/9ZILCzopxQ0/s1600/Screenshot_2013-06-04-13-44-07.png". Here each of the elements of the grid view will open the album. It is these "elements" that I am talking about and want to customize.

Comment: Please, **use an appropriate terminology**. There is only one and one onlly `launcher icon`. So, do you mean the `ActionBar/ToolBar` icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (above your discussion ) you want some imageview or imagebutton where your image will set dynamically . when you click this kind of view (icon) it opens another activity ... so you can use `layer-list` . for more details  [click](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

[image]

Comment: You could not have gotten any more closer at interpreting my problem and suggesting a solution to it. Thanks for the perfect solution.